# Strange vetical spacing in book Class

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, book-design, books

I am using the `book` class for my thesis. However, the default alignment is very strange as shown in the following sample.

[image: example_output]

As it shows, extra space was added between lines so that the content is filled over the whole page. *What I need is to fill the page normally wihout the extra space?*

Comment: revises paragraph spacing

use this

     \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} % Default is 15pt.

Comment: LaTeX wants to avoid things like starting a page with an equation and is generally unable to pagebreak inside of an equation.  Thus, depending on what follows on the next page, LaTeX may have been unable to set the pagebreak in any other way.  `\raggedbottom` can eliminate the extra vertical stretch, but of course that means that the page won't be full.

Comment: A MWE would be also good though...

Comment: @ruben What is a MWE, please?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Where to add \raggedbottom?

Comment: In the preamble.  It will affect the whole document.  FYI, an MWE is a "Minimum Working Example".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you. That works for me for the moment.

Comment: @LaTeXfan, see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: if the next page begins with a multi-line math display, and you are using `amsmath`, there are tactics to allow page breaks under your control; consult the users guide: `texdoc amsmath`.